# mat-select dropdown position not aligned

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-material-table

I'm using some angular material components but something went wrong with  input box and and select option elements.
The select  option is not aligned properly. when i click to see select option list it showing me outside of my current div or can say left side of page which is not correct.

ng -v

```
Angular CLI: 1.7.4
Node: 8.11.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.11
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cdk: 5.2.5
@angular/cli: 1.7.4
@angular/material: 5.2.5
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/core: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.3.2
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.2.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.10.2
@schematics/angular: 0.3.2
@schematics/package-update: 0.3.2
typescript: 2.5.3
webpack: 3.11.0
```

Image is attached how it looks like:

[image: Image is attached how it looks like]

Comment: Please create a small demo over stackblitz.

Answer (score 0):

Plase make sure you have imported BrowserAnimationsModule in your app module and hammerjs in to the main ts file.
Here is the guide line for [angular material](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started)

My app module code:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatTooltipModule, MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule, MatSelectModule } from 
'@angular/material';

@NgModule({
imports: [
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BrowserModule
 ],
 providers: [],
 bootstrap: []
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Main ts code:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import 'hammerjs';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: It is imported in my app.module.ts nad harmer.js also added, i think it's css related  issue , because for come material component it  affect on alignment . suppose my date picker component - when i click on date picker the calendar open at right side of my page, which is totally miss aligned

Comment: got resolved :  reason was i was importing theme css file at wrong place